# Adding multiple WooCommerce Products through jQuery EACH loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a fairly straightforward piece of code to loop through various product IDs, and then adding them in the WooCommerce cart through a simple Ajax request. However, usually only 1 product gets added to the cart.

I tried setting a timeout at the end of the loop, but didn't do much. Any pointers in the right direction?

```
$(document).on("click", "#add_positions", function() {

$(".spotselector option:selected").each(function(){

    var spot_id = $(this).val();

        if(spot_id !== 'noaction'){
            request = $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo get_site_url();?>/?add-to-cart="+spot_id+"&quantity=1",
                type: "post",
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the implementation is wrong here..As you are using POST request, Parameters should be passed in request body and not as query string parameters in URL...
If you want to pass the parameters in Query string,  you should use GET instead of POST.

Comment: I think it should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you pass the parameters in query string or not. The request works. Unfortunately looping with a each loop doesn't correctly work if there are two or more iterations.